# Bounding sum of probabilities of n events given a bound on the probabilities of their pairwise intersections in a general probability space

Tags: probability, inequality

> Let $A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n$ be events in some probability space. State and prove the inclusion-exclusion formula for the probability $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^{n}A_i)$. Show also that
> $$ \mathbb{P}\Big(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i =1}^{n} A_i \Big) \ge \sum_{i}\mathbb{P}(A_i) - \sum_{i<j}\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) $$
> Suppose now that $n \geq2$ and that whenever $i \neq j$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) \leq  \frac{1}{n}$. Show that there is a constant $c$ independent of n such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i}\mathbb{P}(A_i) \leq c\sqrt{n}$.

My question is about the last inequality we are asked to prove in the problem.

Apart from the direct application of the upper bounds on the probabilities of pairwise intersections on the events that yields a bound of order n, which is not good enough for the purposes of the question (we want a 'square root n bound'), I am not sure how to proceed. The problem seems to suggest to use the inequality derived therein (the first one mentioned, the Bonferroni inequality with k = 2 incidentally), but this seems too weak. It also seems that the inequalities mentioned above cannot both be 'sharp' for large n, for otherwise we would be violating the law of total probability. Also, the inclusion/exclusion principle that was derived in the first part of the question does not seem to be too relevant for this part.

Perhaps one will need to consider a finer partition of the union of the events, but with the bounds at hand, it is not clear how to obtain some improvement on the bounds of the intersections of the events.

Additionally, I tried to recast the problem in terms of indicator variables and their expectations (for instance replacing the probabilities of the events by the expectations of the indicator variables corresponding to these events) and tried using some probabilistic inequalities, such as Markov or Chebychev, but to no avail.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use mathjax to write your questions

Answer (score 1):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried and show your work. There's a possibility that this is wrong, and if so, state any issues/concerns that you have.)

Let $ k = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor $.

**Hint:**  Show that $$\sum_{j=1}^k P ( A_{i_j} ) < 2. $$

> The question hints that you should apply the PIE Inequality that they provided.

**Corollary:** By splitting the events into $k+1$ groups each of size $k$ or smaller,

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n P( A_i)  < 2 (k+1 ) \leq 4 \sqrt{n}. $$

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply! I managed to solve the problem with the hint.